# Serial Connection ATMEGA328p

Tags: avr, c, atmega, uart

I wrote up a function to connect via UART and print a string for debugging purposes. But my logic does not add up somehow... I see the line "Random Number" printed in the console but blazingly fast... no matter what I add for a _delay_ms value, it is not usable. Did I miss out on anything?

Why is my delay function not having any influence on the output on the serial terminal?

```
void initUSART(void) {

    #define BAUDRATE ((F_CPU) / (BAUD * 8UL)-1) // Set Baud Rate Value for UBRR

    // Set register
    UBRR0H = (BAUDRATE >> 8);
    UBRR0L = BAUDRATE;
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);  
    // Enable USART transmitter and receiver
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    // Set 8 data bits and 1 stop bit
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

void transmitByte(uint8_t data) {
    // Wait for empty transmit buffer
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = data;
}

void printString(const char myString[]) {
    uint8_t i = 0;
    while (myString[i]) {
        transmitByte(myString[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    setup();    
    randomSeed(adcRead(0));

    while (1) 
    {   
        printString("Random Number:\n");
        _delay_ms(100000);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

When I use `\r\n`at the end of the string, the output gets really strange:

[image]

Comment: Check the [`_delay_ms()` documentation](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrlibcreferencemanual/group__util__delay_1gad22e7a36b80e2f917324dc43a425e9d3.html), there are tricky limits to its input. Have you tried smaller values? Also, what's your F_CPU defined to? Try making your own delay loop with `nop`s or something. Try different enabling or disabling optimizations. As for your `\r` output problem, could it be a problem with the terminal program? Check if the problem persists with a different program.

Comment: The number 100000 is too big for a 16-bit value. Use a smaller delay time (like 100ms) and enclose that delay within a for loop

Comment: @MarkU Did you look at the documentation for `_ms_delay()` I linked in my previous comment? Its argument is a `double`, not a 16-bit integer. He _should_ limit its value, but for different reasons.